# Change a numeric value as a string type in Persian to Latin

Tags: java, android, string

I want to change the local of the numeric string (change all character from source local to destination local eg: -fa to en-   or -mm to en- and vice versa ) for example if I have something like :

```java
String value = "꧱꧲꧳";
```

that is 123 in MYANMAR language, or :

```java
String value = "۱۲۳";
```

that is the same but in the Persian language.

want to change to **123** but with the use of a function that gives the local as a parameter, not by iterate character by character.

The following code changes the number in 'en' to any other local but it has some problem that it gives  a double as a parameter but I need to pass a string:

```java
NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale("fa"));
fmt.setMaximumFractionDigits(100);
String result = fmt.format(123);
```

Comment: Do you know in advance whether the string is in Burmese (Myanmarese) or Persian, or do you have to detect that first?

Comment: @OleV.V. I know that in advance. I want to get a product list from google inappbilling-v3 API that returns the value in the device's local, so I can figure out that the  number's local is the local of the device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That’s built in.

```
    Locale myanmar = Locale.forLanguageTag("my-MM");
    NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance(myanmar);
    
    String value = "꧱꧲꧳";
    Number result = format.parse(value);
    System.out.println(result);
```

Output is:

> 123

Tailor to your needs.

Converting a number to a string is called *formatting*. The opposite conversion is *parsing*. And the methods you need to call to perform those conversions are named accordingly.

Comment: that's worked but only for numbers without decimal places. I edited my post and added a sample code that does the same for decimal numbers. If you think that you can do it in an easier way, please post it.

Comment: Just use `getInstance()` instead of `getIntegerInstance()`.

Comment: Ok and finally you should Converting exponential value to a number format like:`new DecimalFormat("#0.00").format(result)`

Answer (score 0):

So you are trying to convert English formatted numbers to Persian, yeah? This class gives you a bunch of useful methods.

```
tv1.setText(Persian.persianalize(myText);
tv2.setText(Persian.persianalize(myNumber);
```

And the class:

```
public class Persian {

private static String[] persianNumbers = new String[]{ "۰", "۱", "۲", "۳", "۴", "۵", "۶", "۷", "۸", "۹" };

public static String persianalize(String text, boolean zeroToText) {
    if (text==null)
        return "";

    if (text.length() == 0) {
        return "";
    }
    String out = "";
    int length = text.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        char c = text.charAt(i);
        if ('0' <= c && c <= '9') {
            int number = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(c));
            out += persianNumbers[number];
        } else if (c == '٫') {
            out += '،';
        } else {
            out += c;
        }
    }
    if (zeroToText)
        if (out!=null && out.equals("۰"))
            return "صفر";
    return out;
}

public static String convertNumberToEnglish(String num) {
    if (num==null)
        return "";
    String d = num;
    d = d.replace("۰", "0");
    d = d.replace("۱", "1");
    d = d.replace("۲", "2");
    d = d.replace("٣", "3");
    d = d.replace("٤", "4");
    d = d.replace("۵", "5");
    d = d.replace("٦", "6");
    d = d.replace("٧", "7");
    d = d.replace("۸", "8");
    d = d.replace("۹", "9");
    d = d.replace("،", ",");

    return d;
}

public static String persianalize(long value, boolean zeroToText) {
    return persianalize(String.valueOf(value), zeroToText);
}

public static String persianalize(long value) {
    return persianalize(String.valueOf(value), false);
}

public static String persianalize(double value) {
    return persianalize(String.valueOf(value), false);
}

public static String persianalize(String value) {
    return persianalize(value, false);
}
```

}

Comment: Thank's but, As I said i don't want to change it character to character

Comment: Why not? This is the only possible way! Other methods like `NumberFormat` are also using the same approach internally.

Comment: Yeh, but that's only worked for Persian number but I want to change any local to any other.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this extension in kotlin

```
fun String.toJustEnglishNumber(): String {

    var value = ""

    for (character in this.toCharArray()) {

        var str = ""

        when (val ascii = character.toInt()) {

            in 1632..1641 -> {
                // Arabic
                val valueOld = ascii - 1584
                val valueChar = valueOld.toChar()
                str = valueChar.toString()
            }
            in 1776..1785 -> {
                // Persian
                val valueOld = ascii - 1728
                val valueChar = valueOld.toChar()
                str = valueChar.toString()
            }
            in 48..57 -> {
                // English
                str = character.toString()
            }
        }
        value += str
    }
    return value
}
```

and use this way

```
"꧱꧲꧳".toJustEnglishNumber()
```